# Magento - How to add upgrade SQL lines to extension

Tags: sql, xml, magento, upgrade

I'm working on a custom Magento extension. I'm developing the extension at Magento version of 1.9.0.1.

So i have simple question.

I've created an extension and lately i've made some upgrades to it.
The first version of the extension was numbered: 1.0.0

Let me show you the config file of the extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource</resourceModel>
        </smsnotification>
        <vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <smsnotification>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</table>
            </smsnotification>
            <smsnotificationhistory>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsHistory</table>
            </smsnotificationhistory>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <smsnotification_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </smsnotification_setup>
        <smsnotification_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_read>
        <smsnotification_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_write>
    </resources>    
    <events>
    <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after_smsprice_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>smsnotification/newordertotalobserver</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>saveSmspriceTotal</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after_smsprice_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>  
    <checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>     
          <checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single_smsprice_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>smsnotification/newordertotalobserver</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>saveSmspriceTotalForMultishipping</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single_smsprice_handler>      
        </observers>
      </checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single>     
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
     <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>                
                <smsprice_total>
                    <class>smsnotification/quote_address_total_smsprice</class>
                    <after>subtotal,freeshipping,tax_subtotal,shipping</after>
                    <before>grand_total</before>
                </smsprice_total> 
            </totals>
        </quote>
            <order_invoice>
                <totals>                
                <smsprice_total>
                    <class>smsnotification/order_invoice_total_smsprice</class>
                    <after>subtotal,freeshipping,tax_subtotal,shipping</after>
                    <before>grand_total</before>
                </smsprice_total> 
                </totals>
            </order_invoice>
            <order_creditmemo>
                <totals>                
                <smsprice_total>
                    <class>percentpayment/order_creditmemo_total_smsprice</class>
                    <after>subtotal,freeshipping,tax_subtotal,shipping</after>
                    <before>grand_total</before>
                </smsprice_total> 
                </totals>
            </order_creditmemo>
    </sales>    
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <smsnotification>
                <file>smsnotification.xml</file>
            </smsnotification>
        </updates>
    </layout>   
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <default>
    <vivas>
        <smspricegroup>                
            <smsprice_name>SMS Notification</smsprice_name>
            <smsprice_fee>0.5</smsprice_fee>            
        </smspricegroup>      
    </vivas>
    </default>
</config>
```

And the sql installer file located - /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/sql/smsnotification_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php contains:

```
<?php
$installer=$this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `smstext` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `VivasIndustries_SmsHistory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `receiver` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `smstext` text NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

    ");
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

But after the upgrade i've made i have to add this think to MySQL:

```
$installer->addAttribute("quote_address", "smsprice_total", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("order", "smsprice_total", array("type"=>"varchar"));
```

So how can i create an upgrade file and how can this extension understand that it has an upgrade?

I am not even sure i'm giving my question right.

P.S.
I'll export the whole MySQL database of the Magento to search for matches: `smsprice_total` so i can be sure they are created.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrades are generally ran on a production server. If you're in the middle of development just stick them in your original installer file and they will run as long as you drop the table they created and remove the related entry from `core_resource`.

In your case, drop: `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` and `VivasIndustries_SmsHistory`

Then find the entry to `smsnotification_setup` in `core_resource` and delete the row.

If you really want to add an upgrade script just do the following instead:

Change your module version to `1.1.0` or `2.0.0` or `1.0.1` - basically anything higher than the original so that it will detect a discrepancy of versions and run your upgrade script.

```
<version>2.0.0</version>
```

Create the following file matching the version change you've made:

```
mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-1.1.0.php
```

or

`mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-2.0.0.php`

or

`mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php`

Flush cache and perform a single page load.

You'll know that the extension successfully installed if it updated the number for `smsnotification_setup` inside `core_resource` table